# On notation of a linear algebra definition of a set of functions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm confused on a definition in my Linear Algebra textbook, Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler.

> If $S$ is a set, then $F^S$ denotes the set of functions from $S$ to $F$.

Specifically, I'm confused when the author says that the set of functions goes from $S$ to $F$. One of the points of confusion is what he means by "goes" and that $F$ is not defined to be a function, it's defined to be the set of every real or complex number, not a function. If $F$ does not contain functions, how can $F^S$ which is a set of functions be equal to $F$?

Will someone explain the definition more explicitly?

Comment: It's better to write the text directly into the question, which makes the question searchable in the future and also makes the question easier to read.

Comment: I used Latex, is there a better way to write mathematical notation for stack exchange?

Comment: It's good that you used Latex, but rather than posting an image of the question you can type the question here directly.

Comment: Note that in this context the capital $F$ stands for "field", not "function".

Comment: I went ahead and edited the question, you can take a look and see how MathJax is used when writing a question like this.

Comment: I wonder if the statement would have been more clear if the field in question were named $K$ rather than $F$. Then, the definition would state that $K^S$ denotes the set of functions from $S$ to $K$.

Comment: Thanks for the help littleO. I noticed three thumbs down for the question, are people upset that I asked a simple question?  Maybe upset about the format of my question?

Comment: @AndrewFerro I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing the downvotes were mainly for having posted an image of the question. In my opinion the question was fine otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

It means the set of function of the form $f:S\to F$, i.e., the set of functions whose domain is $S$ and their codomain is $F$.

Answer (score 1):

I have just looked this up in Linear Algebra Done Right, Chapter#1 page 14. $\mathbf{F}^S$ denotes the set of all functions from $\mathbf{F}$ to $S$ formally speaking we have
$$\mathbf{F}^S = \{h|h:S\to\mathbf{F}\}$$

where $F$ is the field of either the set of all real numbers or the set of all complex numbers.

Comment: Not seeing this was a failure of my ability to interpret context.